# Javascript feedreader within div

Tags: javascript, xml, html, rss

Implementing a JS script to pull/parse an XML feed and return the contents into an html . Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to be doing so, as nothing but the text (Feed!) between the div tags appears on the page.

```
function loadRSSFeed(param){
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.open("GET",'http://feeds.feedburner.com/engadget/Dnjv',false);
  xmlhttp.send();
  xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;
  var strBuffer= "";
  strBuffer = strBuffer +"<table border='1'>";
  var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("item");
  for (i=0;i<x.length;i++){   
        strBuffer = strBuffer +"<tr><td><a href='";
        strBuffer = strBuffer +(x[i].getElementsByTagName("link")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
        strBuffer = strBuffer +"'>";
        strBuffer = strBuffer +(x[i].getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
        strBuffer = strBuffer +"</a></td></tr><tr><td>";
        strBuffer = strBuffer +(x[i].getElementsByTagName("description")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue.substring(0,180));
        strBuffer = strBuffer + "<a href='";
        strBuffer = strBuffer +(x[i].getElementsByTagName("link")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
        strBuffer = strBuffer +"'>... Read More...</a>";
        strBuffer = strBuffer +"</td></tr>";
        if(i==10){
          break;
        }
    }
  strBuffer = strBuffer +"</table>";
  document.getElementById(param).innerHTML =strBuffer;
}
```

it is imported like so (successfully):
     
Then called in the body

```
<body onload ="loadRSSFeed('feeddisplay');">
  <h1>All the news that's fit to render</h1>
  <div id="feeddisplay">Feed!</div>
</body>
```

But it does not show up! The rest of the page does as it's supposed to...

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The google feed reader api is more robust and has few more features to handle rss

http://code.google.com/apis/feed/v1/

Also I think onLoad may not be able to find the div ... ? did you try executing the script after the div feed was loaded ... just my 2 cents.

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't that be XMLHttp**Request**?